# select * only return one value

Tags: sql-server, select, ado.net

I want select multiple (all) values from table Account.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Account";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        label1.Text = reader["PasswordHash"].ToString();
        connection.Close();
```

Why is this always returning only the first row. Actually it return one row, because if I set in where clause something like `where id = 2 and id = 3` it still returns only one value.
Table have more than one value i checked form Management Studio, there query run as they should.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious: If you want to read multiple rows from the result set, what do you expect label1.Text to look like when you're done?

Comment: Because you're calling `reader.Read()` only once ?!?!?!? That call reads **one row** of the result set - that's all.

Comment: this is just practicing to get full grasp with sql server functionality. Label was easiest thing to start from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are not looping through the query results, it shows up only one result.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Account";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    connection.Open();
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    While(reader.Read())
{
    label1.Text += " " +reader["PasswordHash"].ToString();
}
    connection.Close();
```

The above code loops through the query results and will give you what you want in a concatenated string assigned to `label1.text`. You can also view the results by inserting `Console.WriteLine(reader["PasswordHash"].ToString());` in the `while` loop

Answer (score 3):

You should do

```
while (reader.Read())
    // process information
```

You need to iterate all the information you retrieved.

Sidenote: Use using statements on your SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataReader to make sure the objects get disposed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The reader only advances one record at a time. You'd need to iterate through the result set in a loop:

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    // do something with the current row by accessing reader[]
}
reader.Close();
```

There are better ways to structure your code but this illustrates the point you were missing and requires the least changes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop, something like this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Call Read before accessing data.
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
        reader[0], reader[1]));
}
```

There is an example in the MSDN docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The line `reader.Read()` will get the next row, so you can use `while(reader.Read())` to iterate over the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code my recommendation is to use some other object to add the code to. Text of a label is not an appropriate choice.

Try using a foreach loop into a list to retrieve all the data that has been returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need a while-loop;

```
while(reader.Read()) {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader[0]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `where id = 2 and id = 3` would return zero results as as id=2 and id=3 are mutually exclusive. `where id = 2 or id = 3` could work.

```
while (reader.Read()) { /*Do stuff with current row*/ }
```

could work for iterating through the results

Comment: I was thinking 'or', but I wrote 'and' :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop and data reader is best way for your code , for sample ,something like this:

```
SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
// Always call Read before accessing data.
while (myReader.Read()) {
   Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + myReader.GetString(1));
}
// always call Close when done reading.
myReader.Close();
```